# Importing files from subdirectory using Systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying load a angular2 component that i created. Test.component

Using Systemjs, i set the default extension to js for everything under /app 
For some reason it won't append ".js" to test.component when it tries to look for it. This work if i moves it everything a directory up. 
Can someone explain ?

[image]
[image: HTML Error]

Answer (score 0):

It's a folder problem, let me explain:
here is your current file setup:

```
App
  test_component
    test.html
    test.spec.js
```

In `test.html` you configured `../app` in System.config but since `test.html` is located in `test_component` folder, `../app` doesn't exist, since `../` is already the `app` folder

if you configure `../` instead of `../app`, it should work fine.

or you can simply configure this way:

```
packages:{
    app: {
        defaultExtension:'js'
    }
}
```

without the folder reference.

Comment: Thanks notice the mistake, try it your way but it still fails with same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this configuration:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    app: '../../map'
  },
  packages:{
    app: {
        defaultExtension:'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So the new error is "system.src.js:1061 GET http://localhost:63342/angular/app/test_component/angular2/testing.js 404 (Not Found)"  i try to included it as  <script src="../node_modules/angular2/testing.js"></script> but it gives me an error of require is not defined.